# Using operators on strings in sh

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script that checks a Debian install for the heartbleed vulnerability. It first obtains a list of version numbers of any installed SSL orientated packages:

```
$: dpkg -l | grep ssl | grep amd64 | awk '{print $3}'
1.0.1e-2+deb7u3
1.0.1e-2+deb7u3
1.0.1e-2+deb7u3
```

This is used in a `for` loop to determine whether the version number precedes the fixed releases which would have a version of 1.0.1e-2+deb7u6 or higher:

```
#!/bin/sh
heartbleed_is_fixed() {
    #
    # For each package that uses SSL
    for version in $(dpkg -l | grep ssl | grep amd64 | awk '{print $3}'); do
        #
        # The heartbleed bug was fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.1e2+deb7u6
        # Check each package and if package version is less
        if [[ "$version" < "1.0.1e-2+deb7u6" ]]; then
            #
            # return false, heartbleed is not fixed
            return 1
        fi
    done
    #
    # If we got to this point then the heartbleed bug has been fixed
    return 0
}
```

This **works well in bash** but this script needs to be run in sh. When run in sh it stumbles over the expression in the `if` statement: "cannot open 1.0.1e-2+deb7u6: No such file". It indicates the line number of the if statement so it's apparently misinterpreting the `<` operator as an input stream directive:

```
"$version" < "1.0.1e-2+deb7u6"
```

Edit: The double square brackets (`[[` and `]]`) also causes an error in sh: "[[: not found" but the double brackets are needed by bash to correctly evaluate the expression.

How can I adjust this script so that it works in sh?

Comment: Try to use `-lt` as the "less than" operator instead of `<`. Right now, `<` is interpreted as I/O redirection.

Comment: @rje a good idea but `-lt` is a boolean operator for numeric expressions, not strings; it returns "Illegal number: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u3"

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I was wrong. You want to do a string comparison. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are no boolean operators here. Boolean operators (e.g.: and, or) supposed to work on booleans, not on strings.

In `sh`, there's no `[[`, so you need the good old `[`.

You have to escape `<`:

```
if [ "$version" \< "1.0.1e-2+deb7u6" ]; then
```

You can also use `"<"` or `'<'`, just make sure it's escaped.

Comment: Thanks, i'll edit the question to refer to logical operators, then I'll try your solution!

Comment: Quite right; it worked first time. I've learned shell scripting in a very ad hoc way - if you can recommend any resources that will help me grapple with this sort of thing i'd really appreciate it!

Comment: bash manual + faq http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ . first of all, learn how a line is parsed, what is quoting and escaping, what is a command and its arguments. most problems are caused by misunderstanding or not knowing the very basics of the language.